# EF Core in memory store lists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I'm pretty new to the whole EF Core in memory database concept, so I'm probably missing a few important things here, but I need this figured out sooner or later.

What I'm trying to achieve is Add an object which contains lists of other objects to database.
While the primitive data types are stored correctly, the lists seem to be always null.

```
public class Race
{
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> AllRunningVehicles { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> AllRepairingVehicles { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> AllDeadVehicles { get; set; }

    public Race()
    {
        //AllRunningVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        //AllRepairingVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        //AllDeadVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
    }
}
```

And here is the controller

```
public class RaceController : Controller
{
    private readonly RaceContext _raceContext;

    public RaceController(RaceContext Rcontext)
    {
        _raceContext = Rcontext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Race>> PostRaceItem(int year)
    {
        Race raceItem = new Race();
        raceItem.Year = year;
        raceItem.AllRunningVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        raceItem.AllRepairingVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        raceItem.AllDeadVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        await _raceContext.RaceItems.AddAsync(raceItem);
        await _raceContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return raceItem;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Race>> GetRaceItem(int raceID)
    {
        var raceItem = await _raceContext.RaceItems.FindAsync(raceID);

        if (raceItem == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return raceItem;
    }
}
```

I've tried creating lists in Ctor, but that way they are always empty, the data stored in them is always wiped out, which I don't want to. I will include Context and Startup classes, just in case they need some additional configuration which I'm not aware of.

```
public class RaceContext : DbContext
{
    public RaceContext(DbContextOptions<RaceContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Race> RaceItems { get; set; }
}
```

And the Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<RaceContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("RaceList"));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TEST", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TEST v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think about how you expect the data to be stored in the database when working with EF. In your case, the structure you propose would be pretty much impossible given 3 collections of the same class. Primitive types map to fields in the table, object references and collections map to related tables.

You have two entities that are related: Race and Vehicle. Assuming that several vehicles participate in a race and any one vehicle can participate in several races, that forms a many-to-many relationship. That a vehicle can be "running", "repairing", or "dead", is effectively a state of a vehicle in a given race.

From a database perspective that would mean a Race table, a Vehicle table, and then a joining table called something like RaceVehicles.  The State of a vehicle can be part of the RaceVehicle table/entity:

```
public class Race
{
    [Key]
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    // ... Race details.

    public virtual ICollection<RaceVehicle> RaceVehicles { get; set; } = new List<RaceVehicle>();
}

public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... Vehicle details...
}   

public class RaceVehicle
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("Race")]
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Vehicle")]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    
    public RaceStates State { get; set; } = RaceStates.Running;

    public virtual Race Race { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public enum RaceStates
{
    None = 0,
    Running,
    Repairing,
    Dead
}
```

This is the first step, however for a race it will only give you *all* vehicles in the race, for all states. (running, etc.) As far as entities are concerned they should reflect the data state of your application. When we go to present the details of a race then that is where we will want to break up the vehicles by their race state. We could pass entities to the views, but it is always better to provide views with a model formatted to include just the data the view will need. This helps prevent surprises and allows us to format the data into something suitable to the view:

```
[Serializable]
public class RaceViewModel
{
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    public int RaceYear { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VehicleViewModel> RunningVehicles { get; set; } = new List<VehicleViewModel>();
    public ICollection<VehicleViewModel> RepairingVehicles { get; set; } = new List<VehicleViewModel>();
    public ICollection<VehicleViewModel> DeadVehicles { get; set; } = new List<VehicleViewModel>();

}

[Serializable]
public class VehicleViewModel
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }
    // Vehicle details for the view.
}
```

When we fetch the data, we project our entities (data state) into the view models (view state)

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var viewModels = context.Races
        .Where(r => r.Year >= 2020 /*insert conditions*/)
        .Select(r => new RaceViewModel
        {
            RaceId = r.RaceId,
            RaceYear = r.Year,
            RunningVehicles = r.RaceVehicles
                .Where(rv => rv.State == RaceStates.Running)
                .Select(rv => new VehicleViewModel
                {
                    VehicleId = rv.Vehicle.VehicleId,
                    VehicleName = rv.Vehicle.Name,
                }).ToList(),
            RepairingVehicles = r.RaceVehicles
                .Where(rv => rv.State == RaceStates.Repairing)
                .Select(rv => new VehicleViewModel
                {
                    VehicleId = rv.Vehicle.VehicleId,
                    VehicleName = rv.Vehicle.Name,
                }).ToList(),
            DeadVehicles = r.RaceVehicles
                .Where(rv => rv.State == RaceStates.Dead)
                .Select(rv => new VehicleViewModel
                {
                    VehicleId = rv.Vehicle.VehicleId,
                    VehicleName = rv.Vehicle.Name,
                }).ToList()
         }).ToList();
}
```

This gives you a model suitable for the view that splits up your vehicle lists based on state.  You could set up similar properties in the entity itself that return Vehicles by each state, however you need to configure these so that EF ignores them, and they would only function provided the RaceVehicles collection is loaded. (Either eager loaded, or triggering a lazy load if available)

The benefits of projection with `Select` rather than returning entities is that `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` will automatically adjust the resulting SQL to pull back whatever fields are needed from related tables/entities. If you are returning the entities themselves, you need to remember to eager load *all* of the related entities otherwise you will be incurring stiff performance penalties for lazy load calls or left with #null references if lazy loading is disabled.

Comment: This is a rather detailed explanation. I will give it a try and hopefully solve the issue I'm having. Much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be working partially, as I still have the problem of lists being empty when trying to add new object. In this case:
public virtual ICollection<RaceVehicle> RaceVehicles { get; set; } = new List<RaceVehicle>();
Is always empty when adding new Vehicles to the Race

Comment: If you are loading an existing race from the database in order to update it, you need to use `Include(x => x.RaceVehicles)` to eager load your collection. This is optional only with lazy loading enabled and the RaceVehicles is declared as `virtual`, however even then it is highly recommended.

Comment: Yes, after trying the suggested implementation with eager loading all Lists seem to be loading without any issues, which indeed solves all the problems I've been having. Marking this as accepted.